# Какой формат у результата запроса SELECT сделанного при помощи db.execute?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite3, cs50

Учусь работать в рамках CS50 с базами данных. По заданию надо совершать запросы через `db.execute`. (`db = SQL("sqlite:///finance.db")`; `SQL` импортируется из модуля `CS50`, так что не могу точно сказать, что из себя представляет).

Представим, что мы запросили `n` количество колонок из базы данных и сохранили результат в `results`. В `Python3`(или из-за модуля `CS50`) мы можем обратиться к конкретному значению в первой строке так: `results[0][<имя колонки в кавычках>]`.

Как осуществляется эта сноска? База данных возвращает список словарей, где ключ - это название колонки, а значение - это конкретное значение в строке? Или как? Встречали вы такого типа сноску в `Python3`, или это было написано для сугубо учебных целей? Пытался искать информацию, но не нашел. Объясните, пожалуйста, или киньте ссыль. Хочу понять.

Comment: Судя по тегам про sqlite3, можно попытаться догадаться, что Вам нужно что-то вроде [оф дока](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам полноценный пример для создания SQLite БД (файла), таблицы, заполнения таблицы данными и чтения данных из этой таблицы:

```
import sqlite3

# открыть существующий или создать новый файл SQLite DB    
conn = sqlite3.connect(r"c:/temp/test.sqlite")

# DB cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# данные (строки) для заполнения таблицы    
rows = [(1, "str1", "2018-11-01"),
        (2, "str2", "2018-11-02"),
        (3, "str3", "2018-11-03")
       ]

# создать пустую таблицу "tab"
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tab (id int, name text, dt date)")

# вставить строки в таблицу
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO tab VALUES (?,?,?)", rows)

# зафиксировать транзакцию
conn.commit()

# выполнить SELECT  
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tab")

# чтение результата "SELECT"
# возвращется список строк в виде кортежей
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)

# закрыть соединение с БД
conn.close()
```

результат:

```
(1, 'str1', '2018-11-01')
(2, 'str2', '2018-11-02')
(3, 'str3', '2018-11-03')
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что, если бы мы сохранили результат как `rows = cur.fetchall()`, можно было бы получить доступ к элементу `str1`  так: `rows[0][1]` ?

Comment: @CuriousMind, вы правильно понимаете